# Count results of a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a newbie question here, but I'm really stucked. I have a multidimensional array that comes from a SELECT from a database, what I need is pretty simple, I'm doing a graphic where contains the number of results of each column of every user specified.

Heres some code to clarify your minds:

```
try {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=***; dbname=**;charset=utf8;', '***', '**');

        }catch(PDOException $err){
            echo "Erro:\n".$err->getMessage();
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM results
                WHERE ra like '****'";

        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();

        $resultPgto = array_column($result, 'indicado_pgto');

        print_r($resultadoPgto);
```

This returns me this array:

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "Indicacao Invalida"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Nao"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "Nao"
}
```

I need to count the results that are equal to `Sim` AND it should returns me 0 but instead when I do something like `print_r($resultadoPgto == 'Sim');` it returns '1'...

Other funny fact is, when I try to return results that are equal to `Nao` (theres 2 there) it returns me 0 or 1...

What I'm missing here? Can someone please help?

EDIT 1 :

Counting the result itself will return the number of keys the array has.

Here is the full Result to your understanding.

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(22) {
    ["dsadsad"]=>
    string(7) "***"
    [0]=>
    string(7) "****"
    ["nome_aluno"]=>
    string(25) "lore"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "ipsum"
    ["nome_indicado"]=>
    string(25) "lore"
    [2]=>
    string(25) "ipsum"
    ["indicado_inscrito"]=>
    string(18) "Indica��o Inv�lida"
    [3]=>
    string(18) "Indica��o Inv�lida"
    ["indicado_confirmado"]=>
    string(18) "Indica��o Inv�lida"
    [4]=>
    string(18) "Indica��o Inv�lida"
    ["indicado_presente"]=>
    string(18) "Indica��o Inv�lida"
    [5]=>
    string(18) "Indica��o Inv�lida"
    ["indicado_aprovado"]=>
    string(18) "Indica��o Inv�lida"
    [6]=>
    string(18) "Indica��o Inv�lida"
    ["indicado_matriculado"]=>
    string(18) "Indica��o Inv�lida"
    [7]=>
    string(18) "Indica��o Inv�lida"
    ["indicado_pgto"]=>
    string(18) "Indicacao Invalida"
    [8]=>
    string(18) "Indicacao Invalida"
    ["validacao_indicacao"]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    [9]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    ["validacao_desconto"]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(22) {
    ["dsdsdasda"]=>
    string(7) "***"
    [0]=>
    string(7) "***"
    ["nome_aluno"]=>
    string(25) "lore"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "ipsum"
    ["nome_indicado"]=>
    string(23) "lore"
    [2]=>
    string(23) "ipsum"
    ["indicado_inscrito"]=>
    string(3) "Sim"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "Sim"
    ["indicado_confirmado"]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    ["indicado_presente"]=>
    string(9) "EM ABERTO"
    [5]=>
    string(9) "EM ABERTO"
    ["indicado_aprovado"]=>
    string(9) "EM ABERTO"
    [6]=>
    string(9) "EM ABERTO"
    ["indicado_matriculado"]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    [7]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    ["indicado_pgto"]=>
    string(3) "Nao"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "Nao"
    ["validacao_indicacao"]=>
    string(3) "Sim"
    [9]=>
    string(3) "Sim"
    ["validacao_desconto"]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(22) {
    ["asdasdsad"]=>
    string(7) "***"
    [0]=>
    string(7) "***"
    ["nome_aluno"]=>
    string(25) "lore"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "ipsum"
    ["nome_indicado"]=>
    string(15) "lore"
    [2]=>
    string(15) "ipsum"
    ["indicado_inscrito"]=>
    string(3) "Sim"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "Sim"
    ["indicado_confirmado"]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    ["indicado_presente"]=>
    string(9) "EM ABERTO"
    [5]=>
    string(9) "EM ABERTO"
    ["indicado_aprovado"]=>
    string(9) "EM ABERTO"
    [6]=>
    string(9) "EM ABERTO"
    ["indicado_matriculado"]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    [7]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    ["indicado_pgto"]=>
    string(3) "Nao"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "Nao"
    ["validacao_indicacao"]=>
    string(3) "Sim"
    [9]=>
    string(3) "Sim"
    ["validacao_desconto"]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "N�o"
  }
}
```

The only field I need information is `"indicado_pgto"`, thats why I did the `array_column()`

What I really need is compare each value and count them, to return me any position that have the string `'Sim'` on it, and even if don't have any `'Sim'` string on it, it returns me 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this array after using `array_column()` on the SQL results, then the assumption is that your target array looks like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "Indicacao Invalida"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Nao"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "Nao"
}
```

If so, then you should be able to do something simple like this?

```
<?php

$counter = 0;

foreach ($resultadoPgto as $result) {
    if ($result === 'Nao') {
        $counter++;
    }
}

print_r($counter);
```

Note that I used the triple equality operator `===` instead of the double equality operator`==`.

The weird behaviour you are experiencing with your `print_r($resultadoPgto == 'Sim')` returning '1' or '0' could be an side effect of using the double equality operator since it does not take the data type in consideration when evaluating the expression.

Comment: There you go! I told it was a simple matter, sometimes I feel ashamed of what I'm getting stucked at, but I think this is the process of evolving! haha Thank you so much!

Comment: Yo might want to `echo $counter;` as it is not an array `print_r()` wont work

Answer (score 1):

This will count the occurances of any field in an array that match a specified value.

```
function count_occ($array, $field, $content) {
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach( $array as $a) {
        if ($a[$field] = $content) { $cnt++; }
    }
    return $cnt;
}

echo count_occ($result, 'indicado_pgto', 'Sim');
```

Comment: This works too, thank you for providing such a fast answer, cheers!